# System.Environment.Exit does nothing when button clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tried using:

```
Application.Exit();
```

And:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

But from what I understand, the line I have in my code is just standard for closing a program, and it's what my teacher has in her code (which is how I'm building my project, copying out her code for buttons etc).

```
namespace atmproject
{
   public partial class form1welc : Form
   {
      //VARIABLES
      public static form1welc Welcome = new form1welc();
      public form1welc()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void welcexitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         System.Environment.Exit(0);
      }

      private void welcloginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         custlogin Customers = new custlogin();
         this.Hide();
         Customers.Show();
      }

      private void welcustbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         createcust Customers = new createcust();
         this.Hide();
         Customers.Show();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the button is actually calling `welcexitbtn_Click`? If you put a breakpoint on that line, does it hit it?

Comment: Chances are, if you copy-pasted the code yourself, the Winforms Designer code may not have been generated to actually wire the button click to that handler.

Comment: Note that the canonical case here is, "my button is clicked and nothing happens", or more generally "I took the action that should have fired an event, but nothing happened".

Comment: Given that your problem was apparently that your click event handler method was not "wired up" (specified as the button's click event handler), I'll just mention that this kind of error is usually flagged by ReSharper, and presumably by other similar coding aids, probably even by Visual Studio's code analysis feature if turned on. Anyway, ReSharper says "private method not used" or something similar.

Comment: The teacher is a 'her', would have loved that at my programming lessons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure the button's `Click` event is "wired" to that method in the designer.  If you click on the button in the designer, then check in Events, you can pick your method to run.

This happens automatically if you double-click on the button in the designer, but if you just copy/paste the code in the method, it won't add the event handler automatically.

Comment: Simply double click on the button in the designer. If you wired it up correctly, you'll jump to your handler. If you didn't wire it up correctly, it will create a *new* handler that is empty. In that case, just cut your old handler and paste the meat into the newly created one.

Comment: I was sure I'd double-clicked into all my buttons, but must have missed that one. Been up all night working on it so pretty dazed. Thanks for helping me, I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter -1 like

```
System.Environment.Exit(-1);
```

This will work as expected.

Comment: the poster already uses this code, maybe you could explain why your code would make a difference?